# Jquery UI Datepicker set default value with dateFormat dd.mm.yy

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

How can I set the default value for the jquery datepicker input field to the current day in this format: "dd.mm.yy"?

I'm able to format the chosen/picked date to that format via:

```
$("#datepickerFrom").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"});
```

It will properly give me the date format I need:

```
03.08.2020
```

But I can't figure out how to set the default value of the input field to represent today's date while also being displayed in that format.

Answer (score 0):

Okay turns out this was easier than I feared:

```
$("#datepickerFrom").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```